# How to insert text to both text fields - small code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I wrote a code so I can autofill a webpage, the issue is that i want it to autofill 2 text fields but my code is only filling the first one.
My knowledge is very limited so I don't know how to autofill the second text field with a different phrase.

```js
let question = document.querySelector('crowd-form tr');
if (question) {
  let text = question.textContent.trim();
  let input = question.querySelector('input');
  if (input) {
    // Does text contain "man united"?
    if (text.includes('man united')) input.value = 'Manchester United F.C.';
    // Does text contain "manchester united"?
    else if (text.includes('manchester united')) input.value = 'Manchester United F.C.';
  }
}
```

In the example above, I'm able to insert the team name "Manchester United F.C." but I would like it to fullfill the other field with "Old Trafford".
Can anyone help me?

Comment: `I would like it to fullfill the other field with "Old Trafford".` I did not understand this line. Can you please elaborate little more.

Comment: Hello. This webpage contains two text fields: https://i.imgur.com/JxH5nQn.jpg

I would like a script that is able to autofill both text fields, each of them with a different text.

If a webpage contains **_man united_**, I'd like it to autofill the first textbox with _"Manchester United"_ and the second textbox with _"Old Trafford"_.
As seen in the link above, the current javascript code is only able to autofill the first text box. I don't know how to autofill the other one :(

Comment: Your `if` and `else` both the conditions adding the same value in `input`. Did you put that by mistake or intentionally ?

Comment: It was intentional. My full code has a couple more `elses` and each of them have different value in `inputs`.
I have `else`s to every Premier League team and for each team I had to include some different ways of spelling their names. For Manchester United, i added `man united`, `manunited`, `red devils`, etc.

Comment: Okay now I got it. Can I come up with the solution by tomorrow morning ? That will be fine for you ?

Comment: Oh, take the time you need. I really appreciate your goodwill to help me  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created below snippet. Can you please have a look and check if it works as per your requirement.

```js
// Instead of using querySelector() I directly added the text just for an example.
let text = 'man united is too shit for ronaldo';

// Reference of first textbox.
let firstInput = document.getElementById('firstTextbox');
// Reference of second textbox.
let secondInput = document.getElementById('secondTextbox');

// Assigning the value in firstTextbox based on the question text.
if (firstInput) {
  firstInput.value = text.includes('man united') ? 'Man United F.C.' : text.includes('manchester united') ? 'Manchester United F.C.' : '';
}

// Assigning the value in secondTextbox.
if (secondInput) {
  secondInput.value = 'Old Trafford';
}
```

```html
<input id="firstTextbox" type="text"/>
<input id="secondTextbox" type="text"/>
```

Comment: I don't know what happened to my last reply to your answer but your code worked for me! Thank you so much for helping me out